# Is nabla/del defined for $\nabla{V(x(t),t)}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I stumbled upon [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation#Deriving_the_equation), where they write $\nabla V(x(t), t)$. But, because $x$ is a function of $t$, isn't we suppose to use the ordinary derivative of $V$ instead? I mean isn't the following wrong:
$$
\nabla V(x(t),t)=\Bigg( \frac{\partial V(x(t),t)}{\partial x},\frac{\partial V(x(t),t)}{\partial y},\frac{\partial V(x(t),t)}{\partial z}\Bigg) \quad ?
$$
I'm not interested in the equation in the article, just the notation $∇V(x(t), t)$.

Comment: The eq. correct. Compare $\nabla V$ with $dV/dt$.

Comment: It's just the notation for the function $\nabla V$ evaluated at $x(t)$. I think it's rather unambiguous. Note that $\nabla V(x(t),t)$ is not the total derivative of $V(x(t),t)$ as a function of $t$. To compute the total derivative you need to apply the chain rule, which is precisely what your article did.